# Rails Webpacker not seeing process.env variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

According to this doc
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/env.md

I can simply set variables up in an `.env` file and use Foreman to start Rails. That'll pick up those variables, and from there I can use `process.env.variableName` in my javascript code.

I'm doing that, and yet my process.env object is empty.

Any successfully getting this to work with just a `Foreman / .env` combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `—env` flag and specify your file.

It should work with a `.env` in the same directory though..

From Foreman:

**ENVIRONMENT**

If a .env file exists in the current directory, the default environment will be read from it. This file should contain key/value pairs, separated by =, with one key/value pair per line.

`FOO=bar
BAZ=qux`

http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/

Also you mention you run Rails with Foreman, but just for the obvious, you also run `./bin/webpack-dev-server` via Foreman then right? It is mentioned in the first line of the docs :P

Foreman can run anything, here's an example:

```
portal: bundle exec rails s -p 5001
keyes: cd ../*keyes* && bundle exec rails s -p 7001
cas: catalina run
redis: redis-server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -L log/sidekiq.log
client: sh -c 'rm app/assets/webpack/* || true && cd client && npm run build:development'
monitor: cd ../*monitor* && bundle exec unicorn -p 5003
adrescodeboek: cd ../*adrescodeboek* && bundle exec unicorn -p 5002
citadel: cd ../*citadel* && bundle exec unicorn -p 5004
elasticsearch: elasticsearch
```

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't Foreman by default pick up `.env`? I'll try Foreman with webpack..

Comment: Foreman can be used to run any process, i added an example to my answer.